# Static constructor in abstract class?

Tags: java, abstract-class, static-constructor

Consider the following sample situation:

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    private ByteBuffer buffer;

    /* Some default method implementations, interacting with buffer */

    public static Parent allocate(int len)
    {
        // I want to provide a default implementation of this -- something like:
        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(len);
        return p;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent
{
    /* ... */
}

public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // I want to ultimately do something like:
        Child c = Child.allocate(10);
        // Which would create a new child with its buffer initialized.
    }
}
```

Obviously, I can't do this (`new Parent()`) since Parent is abstract, but I don't *really* want a Parent.  I want this method to be automatically provided to subclasses.

I would prefer to use the "static constructor" approach with `.allocate()` instead of adding another visible constructor.

Do I have any way to put this default implementation in the `Parent` class, or must each of the subclasses contain the same code?

I guess another option would be to strip "abstract" from the parent, but abstract fits -- I never want an object of type Parent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Static methods are not inherited by subclasses, so this approach is fundamentally flawed. Perhaps you want a builder instead?

Comment: How are you going to use it? Can you show an example? To call `Child.allocate` you need to implement static method in `Child`.

Comment: Also, take a look on [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern)

Comment: There is no such thing as a static constructor.

Comment: lol at the close -- its pretty clear this is a real question -- sigh

Comment: @EJP: ... hence the "scare quotes" (ps. there's no such thing as scare quotes either)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you examine the collection of Buffer classes in the standard JDK you will notice that each specialization (ByteBuffer, CharBuffer, DoubleBuffer etc) each have their own static `allocate` method defined. There is a reason they do not all inherit from a common base class - static methods are not inherited! Instead they are associated with the class in which they are defined and only have access to class level variables.

A better pattern for what you are trying to accomplish is the builder/factory pattern. You can examine the JAX-RS [`Response`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0-m01/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.java) class, or [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.java) classes for examples on how to implement these patterns.

Comment: Definitely an oversight that I assumed static methods would be inherited.  And despite referencing the *Buffer `allocate`, I didn't even think to look at its implementation.  Thanks for the suggestions.